Scrapy Playwright Spiders don't always scrape everything
I'm currently having some problems with my Scrapy Spider. I'm scraping all the stats of all NBA players in all seasons. However, only a few pages are scraped while other pages are skipped. Whenever I re-scrape everything, some other different pages are scraped and the rest are not. The outcome is very inconsistent.
import json
import scrapy
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from NBA.items import nba_scraping
import re
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright

class NbaScraping(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "nba"

    @classmethod
    def update_settings(cls, settings) -> None:
        super().update_settings(settings)
        settings.set("PLAYWRIGHT_BROWSER_TYPE", "chromium") # or "firefox" or "webkit"
        settings.set("PLAYWRIGHT_MAX_CONTEXTS", 1)
        settings.set("PLAYWRIGHT_MAX_PAGES_PER_CONTEXT", 1)
        settings.set("PLAYWRIGHT_LAUNCH_OPTIONS", {"headless": False})

    def start_requests(self):
        start_urls = []
        for page in range(1, 4):
            start_urls.append(
                f"https://www.nba.com/stats/players/traditional?SeasonType=Regular+Season&Season={1995+page}-{str(96+page).zfill(2)}"
            )
        start_urls.append(
            "https://www.nba.com/stats/players/traditional?SeasonType=Regular+Season&Season=1999-00"
        )
        for page in range(1, 25):
            start_urls.append(
                f"https://www.nba.com/stats/players/traditional?SeasonType=Regular+Season&Season={1999+page}-{str(page).zfill(2)}"
            )

        for url in start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
            url=url,
                meta={
                    "playwright": True,
                    "playwright_include_page": True,
                },
                callback=self.parse,
                errback=self.errback_close_page,
        )

    async def errback_close_page(self, failure):
        page = failure.request.meta["playwright_page"]
        await page.close()

    async def parse(self, response):
        page = response.meta["playwright_page"]

        year_match = re.search(r"Season=(\d{4})-\d{2}", response.url)
        if year_match:
            year = int(year_match.group(1))
        else:
            if "1900-00" in response.url:
                year = 1999
            else:
                year = None
                self.logger.warning(f"Could not extract the year from the URL: {response.url}")

        # Wait for the dropdowns to be available
        await page.wait_for_selector("select.DropDown_select__4pIg9")

        # Find all dropdowns with the class DropDown_select__4pIg9
        dropdowns = await page.query_selector_all("select.DropDown_select__4pIg9")

        # Iterate through the dropdowns to find the one with the -1 option
        for dropdown in dropdowns:
            options = await dropdown.query_selector_all("option")
            for option in options:
                if await option.get_attribute("value") == "-1":
                    await dropdown.select_option(value="-1")
                    break

        # Wait for the table to be available
        # await page.wait_for_selector("Crom_table__p1iZz")

        soup = BeautifulSoup(await page.content(), "html.parser")

        await page.close()

        # players' name
        player_lst = []
        players = soup.find_all(
            "a", class_=["Anchor_anchor__cSc3P", "Crom_stickySecondColumn__29Dwf"]
        )
        for player in players:
            href = player.get("href", "")
            match = re.search(r"stats/player/(\d+)", href)
            if match:
                player_name = player.get_text()
                player_lst.append(player_name)

        # teams' name
        team_lst = []
        teams = soup.find_all("a", class_=["Crom_text__NpR1_", "Anchor_anchor__cSc3P"])
        for team in teams:
            href = team.get("href", "")
            match = re.search(r"stats/team/(\d+)", href)
            if match:
                team_name = team.get_text()
                team_lst.append(team_name)

        # stats
        stats_lst = []
        tbody = soup.find("tbody", class_="Crom_body__UYOcU")
        if tbody:
            rows = tbody.find_all("tr")
            for row in rows:
                stats = row.find_all("td")
                row_stats = []
                for stat in stats:
                    player_stat = stat.get_text()
                    row_stats.append(player_stat)
                stats_lst.append(row_stats)

        for i in range(len(stats_lst)):
            stats_lst[i] = (stats_lst[i])[3:]

        player_team_mapping = zip(player_lst, team_lst, stats_lst)

        for player, team, stat in player_team_mapping:
            dictionary = nba_scraping(
                player=player,
                team=team,
                year=year,
                age=stat[0],
                gp=int(stat[1]),
                wins=int(stat[2]),
                losses=int(stat[3]),
                min=float(stat[4]),
                pts=float(stat[5]),
                fgm=float(stat[6]),
                fga=float(stat[7]),
                fg_pct=float(stat[8]),
                three_pm=float(stat[9]),
                three_pa=float(stat[10]),
                three_ppct=float(stat[11]),
                ftm=float(stat[12]),
                fta=float(stat[13]),
                ft_pct=float(stat[14]),
                oreb=float(stat[15]),
                dreb=float(stat[16]),
                reb=float(stat[17]),
                ast=float(stat[18]),
                tov=float(stat[19]),
                stl=float(stat[20]),
                blk=float(stat[21]),
                pf=float(stat[22]),
                fp=float(stat[23]),
                dd2=float(stat[24]),
                td3=float(stat[25]),
                plus_minus_box=float(stat[26]),
            )
            yield dictionary


The issue can be fixed by implementing better request handling and page loading. Set CONCURRENT_REQUESTS=1 and add DOWNLOAD_DELAY to avoid overwhelming the server. Wait for networkidle state and add explicit waits for selectors. Handle dropdowns properly with retries and additional waits after selection. Add error handling, validate data before processing, and implement proper page closure. These changes will make the spider more reliable at scraping all pages consistently.

why not just use the nba api?
